# Notepad++ and MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows, notepad++

I'm trying to work with a MySQL server through the notepad++ console. I can navigate to the bin directory of MySQL server, but when I run MySQL:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

The console just says `Process started >>>` and then doesn't ask for my password, or accept any other input. What is going on? I'd much rather work through the notepad++ console than the windows command prompt.

Comment: Are you talking about NppExec plugin? Does the same command actually work in Windows command prompt?

Comment: yes the command works in command prompt, and yes I'm talking about NppExec

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is using file IO similar to *nix systems or old MS-DOS.  The "<" is actually a command line directive, but you're telling Notepad++ to run the mysql.exe program directly (bypassing the command line altogether, so the input directive will be completely ignored).

The solution is to create a batch file.

Example (a file named "C:\exec_mysql.bat"):

```
"C:\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root < %1
PAUSE
```

Then in Notepad++ execute your batch file instead:

```
"C:\exec_mysql.bat" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

This will pass the parameter as expected, launch MySQL and pass in the file.